# What US laws exist around storing/processing personal data of US citizens outside of US?

Tags: privacy

If a company is located in the European Union and stores all personal data in EU servers (to comply with EU regulations), will it comply with US regulations (including state laws)?

Here are few related links, but I'm not sure if  i understood them correctly:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_laws_of_the_United_States

[Do US companies have an obligation to protect of personal information?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/do-us-companies-have-an-obligation-to-protect-of-personal-information)

http://us.practicallaw.com/6-502-0467

Comment: In general, EU law is much more protective of individual privacy than US law, so I would guess that compliance with EU law implies compliance with US law.

Comment: Could someone move it back to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com ?  There are much higher chances to get answer, as people meet that problem frequently (i believe so)  (-: